# Problem accessing to REST API from devices on same network

Tags: node.js, vuejs2

I have a REST API running in my PC and vuejs web app sending request.
When I try the app in localhost, found perfectly.
I can access to home ('/') and using the web app, it send others requests at the API ('/something')

But, i need to try app from my mobile, so I connect both at same network and access to localhost from IP.

I can access to home (IP:port) and the app responde from my mobile.
I can access to others endpoints too (IP:port/something).
Normaly only the app use API endpoints. (Useless for the user to access directly)

The problem is: I'm on home page from my mobile, but at start, the web app send a request to an endpoint. But the server respond 0 to status :(

I try with other PC and same... when i try my app from others devices, the app can't use my API.

**Connexion to home:** (server.js (API))

```
MyRouter.route('/')
.all(function(req, res){
    res.render('home.ejs');
});
```

**Request sended when user access to home (when Vue mounted):** (app.js (Application))

```
mounted () {
   this.$http.get(this.website + '/connexion' ).then(response => {
      //succes (I need to get some infos from API)
   }, response => {
      //error
   }
```

**Endpoint: (server.js)**

```
MyRouter.route('/connexion')
.get(function(req,res){ 
    res.json({foo: "bar"}); //some infos
})
```

From localhost I can get json info but from others device I can access home page but the request to endpoint return request status = 0. When I try to access directly to the endpoint it found ! But I need to still on home page...

Comment: When you load the webpage, are the requests from the webpage sent to localhost ?

Comment: Yep, i print 'this.webpage' it refer to localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find the problem... xD From others device i access to the web app from server IP but the variable 'this.website' used in requests was always "localhost" ! So I replaced that by current URL...

Answer (score 0):

Some of the situations that produce this status code:

Illegal cross origin request (see CORS)

Firewall block or filtering

The request itself was cancelled in code

I'd bet it's CORS or firewall problem.

Comment: The connection used is that of my phone, I will look at it